# Link unclickable due to position?

Tags: html

I came up with a strange issues where link on a page of my website are unclickable.

Still, when I look across the DOM they are there pointing to the write page.

However when I "inspect the element" with google DevTool on the precise link it is not sending me to link(s) into the DOM but to the next element. As if the link wasn't placed here into the page.

You can have a look -> [Try to click on any cities link](http://www.agencedevoyage.com/voyage/europe/italie/)  ("Palerm, Milan ...")

If some of you have already encounter this problem I'll be glad to get a bit of help on this one :)

Comment: Your HTML is not valid, try to fix it, there should be no errors: https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.agencedevoyage.com%2Fvoyage%2Feurope%2Fitalie%2F

Comment: It looks like there is an open HTML tag somewhere in your code...

Comment: Hum ok I'll go check this then

Comment: you should also note that many italian names contains single quotes and you should escape all the single quotes in the names. I have seen in @ReeCube link that there is a "d'Oro" name that is causing many issues. This is also due to the point that you use the html attribute with single quote instead of double

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `#left` is `float: left;` but `h1.titleSectionVoyage` is not. So `h1.titleSectionVoyage` covers your links.

Clear float for `h1.titleSectionVoyage`:

```
h1.titleSectionVoyage {
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: 'Right, really well seen :) Thank you I'll accept your answer as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

As the comments said, there's some issues with your html tagging. Right clicking on firefox and showing the source code of the website will reveal that some `<span>` tags are not correctly closed. That's a likely cause of your issue.